# CSS align a and text in an li tag

Tags: html, css

Here's what I am looking to create. The dollar amounts are linked to a form submit by jQuery.

[image]

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<div class="donate_left_column">
    <p>You can be the autemped lorem ipsum quisciis alic to dolupidebis consed deo vellor quam quam re:</p>
    <div class="donate_amounttable">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="donate_click" id="100" href="#">$100</a>provides 20 new novels for a college prep language arts class.</li>
            <li><a class="donate_click" id="200" href="#">$200</a>provides 1 week of childcare for a parent starting a new job.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.donate_amounttable 
{
}

.donate_amounttable ul
{
    display: inline;

}

.donate_amounttable li
{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.donate_amounttable a
{
    display: block; 
    font-family: din-condensed-web,sans-serif;
    background-color: #bfd475;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

The problem is that it ends up looking like this:

[image]

Here's a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/rboarman/6G8wr/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not using <table> to display. I know people despise using table sometimes, but the reason why the table exists is it is for showing data. I think for your use case, table should be good enough.

Comment: You realise that, outside of HTML5, `id="200"` is invalid? (As is any `id` that starts with a number.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css is only having some little margin problems.
Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6G8wr/2/

Comment: Your solution was the cleanest and worked right away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is best what I found for now: http://jsfiddle.net/6G8wr/6/

I used `<sup>` tag which is used for superscript text and a little styling.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    div.donate_amounttable li
    {
        width:275px;
        display:block;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        clear:both;
        padding:5px 0;
    }

    div.donate_amounttable a
    {
        display: block; 
        font-family: din-condensed-web,sans-serif;
        background-color: #bfd475;
        padding:5px 5px 5px 15px;
        width: 50px;
        font-size: 24px;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: right;
        float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
```

You can view a working model here:
http://ninja-code.net/extra/stackoverflow_test2.php

You can tweak it to add more spacing or make the li longer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you main problem is floating the image and then not clearing.  That makes your LI elements not wrap their children the way they normally would.  This will take care of images and float them and it should also wrap nicely.

```
<style>
.donate_amounttable
{
}

.donate_amounttable ul
{    
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.donate_amounttable ul li
{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    width: 450px;
}


.wordSpacing {
float: left;
margin-left: 12px;
width: 310px;
}
.donate_amounttable a
{
    display: block;    
    font-family: din-condensed-web,sans-serif;
    background-color: #bfd475;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
</style>
```

You'll have to add some tags here to get th word wrapping that you want and to make sure that the LI spans both child elements.

```
<div class="donate_amounttable">
 <ul>
  <li><a class="donate_click" id="100" href="#">$100</a><div class="wordSpacing">provides 20 new novels for a college prep language arts class.</div><div style="clear: left;"></div></li>
  <li><a class="donate_click" id="200" href="#">$200</a><div class="wordSpacing">provides 1 week of childcare for a parent starting a new job.</div><div style="clear: left;"></div></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4GvQS/